# Jetbot: servoserial module not found (python)

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I bought the NVIDIA Jetbot [(link here)](https://www.yahboom.net/study/JETBOT) and am currently working through the steps. However, I cannot import the `servoserial` module package (I'm working in JupyterLab) as I am prompted with "module not found." Why is this the case and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
import serial
```

Link over here...

[Click Me](https://makerprojekt.com/portfolio/python-arduino-servo-control/)

I would like to say that please do some googling